# scale the marker size and color with data values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a simple scatter plot in python but I can't figure out how to scale (i) the size of the markers with the x-y axis range and (ii) the color of the markers with a 3rd variable (such that colors will span the full colormap range).

This is something trivial to do with IDL for instance but I can't find a simple solution with matplotlib.

Any idea would be appreciated !

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is a simple example.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [10.,60.]
y = [30.,90.]
z = [3.,8.] # = diameters of x and y points 

plt.xlim(0., 100.)
plt.ylim(0., 100.)
plt.scatter(x,y,s=my_marker_size,marker='o')
```

How to define my_marker_size such that my points are represented by circles with diameters given by z on this plot ?

Comment: Did you not find it in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)?

Comment: well not really that's why I'm asking here. For the color-coding I ended up with something that seems to work but for the markersize I have no idea how to do it because the plt.scatter argument for size is the marker area "s" which cannot be scaled with the x-y axis values. At least I don't see it in the doc. Any advice welcome ;)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what *scaling with the x-y axis values* means. You should add a sample data and expected output to your question.

Comment: OK no worries, I will edit my post with an example.

Comment: Any idea ?... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.Circle` creates circles that can be added to the plot. Setting the aspect ratio to `'equal'` makes that the circles don't get stretched to look as ovals.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [10., 60.]
y = [30., 90.]
z = [3., 8.] 

ax = plt.gca()
for xi, yi, diam in zip(x, y, z):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((xi, yi), diam))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.xlim(0., 100.)
plt.ylim(0., 100.)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]